# Closure: Why does Britain adopt EU initiatives with greater zest than other more Europhilic member states?

Tags: discussion

Why was [Why does Britain adopt EU initiatives with greater zest than other more Europhilic member states?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/20366/6241) closed 'as unclear'?

Answer (score 10):

I voted to close the question as it's asking for an answer **based on an opinion piece for a book** and that the excerpt that you included **doesn't include any examples of EU initiatives** that the UK adopted "with greater zest than other more Europhilic member states".

---

In addition, the question in the title and the body seem to be different.

- The question in the title is **asking for the reason why "Britain adopt EU initiatives with greater zest than other more Europhilic member states"**.

  - IMO this's **primarily opinion-based** unless examples are cited. One can also that Germany's quite enthusiastic in the EU, so they would adopt EU initiatives with zest too. It would be **much better to includes a few EU initiatives** that the UK adopted with "greater zest", rather than just including an excerpt from a book.
- The question in the body seems to be **questioning the contradiction in the excerpt**.

  - This can't really be answered since it's **more about the author's use of words**, which is off-topic as it's not "about governments, policies or political processes" and may be better suited on EL&U.SE.

The question can be improved if:

- Examples of EU policies that the UK adopted with "greater zest than other more Europhilic member states" are included, in addition to the excerpt.
- The contradiction of the title and body is resolved.

---

**So, basically, that's my reason for voting to close the question. I'd be happy to vote to reopen it when the outstanding issues are resolved.**

Comment: Thanks. I don't remember the author ever exemplifying this assertion.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to explain a phenomenon or event then the first step should always be to make sure that it actually happened.

Far too often do I see people "explain" phenomenons or events without making sure that it actually happened; this is a common fallacy with "cranks" on topics such as UFOs, conspiracy theories, astrology, quack medical claims, etc. However this fallacy is made outside of those fringe topics – such as political questions – as well.

This – above all – is the problem with questions such as this: you're asking us to "explain" things that may not actually have happened. In your specific question it's quite plausible that the claim is true, but it's also plausible that it's baseless.